# Namespace в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, chrome-extension

При разборе мануала по использованию API от Яндекса столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Непонятно откуда берется(или как/где подключается) объект `ya` в этой строчке:

```
var AudioPlayer = ya.music.Audio;
```

Что собственно и приводит к ошибке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следовал строго [инструкции](https://tech.yandex.ru/audio/jsapi/doc/quick-start/index-docpage/#flash-applet).

---

js файлы подключаю в такой последовательности:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">  
    <script src="https://music.yandex.ru/api/audio/dist/index.js"></script>
    <script src="/index.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>       
</head>
```

Console:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://music.yandex.ru/api/audio/dist/index.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

но такая ошибка выходит, если убрать `type=javascript', если его оставить, то ошибки нет, но скрипт по-прежнему не подгружается

Comment: вы файл то подключили? https://tech.yandex.ru/audio/jsapi/doc/quick-start/index-docpage/#load

Comment: @ThisMan, да, конечно.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос как именно подключаете. Возможно `index.js` подгружается раньше, чем код Яндекса

Comment: скрипт по адресу добавляет в `window` св-во `ya`, то есть скорее всего проблема в загрузке файла

Comment: @ThisMan, как это можно посмотреть? Я далек от javascript

Comment: вообще все выглядит прилично, но попробуйте в конец `body` добавить загрузку скриптов + попробуйте адрес по ссылке, которую я привел

Comment: @ThisMan, не помогло, в общем очень странно, похоже на типичную проблему однако

Comment: попробуйте не загружать `index.js`, а только файл Яндекса и в консоли посмотрите, есть ли доступ к `window.ya`? Сложно еще что-то предположить

Comment: @ThisMan, undefined, может ли дело быть в антивирусе и т.д.?

Comment: Вы делаете сайт или расширение для Хрома?

Comment: @TotalPusher. Расширение, сейчас вроде понял что нужно в манифесте что-то прописать, пока в поисках ответа

Comment: Вы на верном пути. Я всего лишь прочитал сообщение об ошибке. Читайте сообщения об ошибках! https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
Ищите на ней "Remote Script
". Как исправите, оформите в виде ответа на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Перво-наперво, загрузи сайт в браузере Хром или яндекс, нажми f12, справа зайди в опцию console. Там и глянь, красным будет помечено, что у тебя не загружено. Отсюда и пляши. Скорее всего яндекс не подгружается. Кстати лучше будет если ты этот файл скачаешь и будешь загружать локально.

Comment: собственно оттуда и начал я плясать)

Comment: в общем ваш совет скопировать файл локально мне помог. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если сделать строго по инструкции то всё работает!

```js
var dom = {
    play: document.querySelector(".controls_play"),
    overlay: document.querySelector(".overlay")
};
var audioPlayer = new ya.music.Audio(null, dom.overlay);
console.log(audioPlayer);
```

```css
.controls_play {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px #aaa solid;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.controls_play:hover {
    border-color: #666;
}
.overlay {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.overlay_hidden {
    display: none;
}
.overlay_error {
    background: #ffcccc;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://music.yandex.ru/api/audio/dist/index.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="player">
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="controls_play">Play</button>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Видимо проблема касается локально меня, но у меня работает только если я подключаю скрипт локально, предварительно скопировав

Comment: @Gardes, а в консоли браузера есть какие-то сообщения о блокировке или ошибке загрузки файлов?

Comment: Да, как раз заметил, обновил

Comment: @Gardes так вы расширение пишете?

Comment: @norbornen, да, и скорее проблема в manifest файле

Comment: @Gardes конечно проблема в недостаточных настройках в manifest.json

Answer (score 1):

Изучив вывод консоли:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://music.yandex.ru/api/audio/dist/index.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

пришел к выводу что проблема в manifest.json файле. Необходимо было прописать значение в свойстве `content_security_policy`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,   
    /*---*/
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://music.yandex.ru/*"],
            "js": ["index.js"]
        }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://music.yandex.ru; object-src 'self'",
    /*---*/
}
```

[источник](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)